# How to do modulo operation in a MPC scheme like ABY?

Tags: multiparty-computation

In MPC schemes like ABY or MOTION, the modulo operation is based on a ring $Z_{2^l}$. So for arithmetic sharing, it is relatively easy to make addition operation in the ring.
My question is, what if I want to do addition in a modulo different from $Z_{2^l}$. Say I want to compute $a+b\ mod\  p$, should I find a corresponding boolean circuit to realize it in the bool sharing or are there other ways?